# Google Map API Custom Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a custom marker that is an image. However, whenever I add "icon: image;" to my code, the map no longer shows up. Where did I go wrong?

```
var image = 'assets/marker.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
                map: map,
                icon: image;
            });
```

Comment: Word of advice, run your JS code through something like http://www.jslint.com/ to identify errors

Answer (score 2):

Remove semi-column which is after "icon:image".